# Firebase sendSignInLinkToEmail "UNAUTHORIZED DOMAIN" error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm testing out Email Link Authentication on my dev site, and am running into the below error when calling `sendSignInLinkToEmail`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN : Domain not whitelisted by project",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN : Domain not whitelisted by project",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`Email link (passwordless sign-in)` is enabled in my Firebase console authentication settings, and my dev site is whitelisted. I've also tried deploying to a whitelisted custom hosting site. The mind boggles on this one.

Comment: have you managed to solve this problem. I am in the same place.

Comment: @KamilLewandowski yes it's been solved. I remember not knowing what happened and it started working suddenly, so I'm guessing it took a bit of time for the whitelist to propagate, or perhaps I had a typo somewhere.

Comment: My solution was a stupid mistake. I was using an environment variable to set the ActionCodeSettings url param to the wrong domain.